# What are the benefits of controlling Mecatol Rex?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-4th-edition

Control of Mecatol Rex is very important to the story of TI, so I assume it's also an important part of gameplay.

When I first read the rules I was surprised to learn that controlling MR does not ensure overall victory, but rather bestows a variety of benefits.

What are all the benefits of controlling Mecatol Rex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The primary benefit is points.  You get one point for being the first person to take Mecatol Rex (from the custodians token) and you can score a point if you control Mecatol Rex and play the Imperial strategy card:

> Gain 1 point if you control Mecatol Rex; otherwise, draw 1 secret objective.

I can tell you from experience that even one or two bonus points are hugely impactful.  In most of the games I've played, the winner has scored at least 1 point from Mecatol Rex.  This is because the public objectives are, on average, roughly symmetric; they are available to all players, and each player has roughly the same ability to achieve them (with caveats for differences in starting positions and faction abilities, such as Jol-Nar being better at technology objectives).  Players can only get 3 secret objectives, and this limit is also the same for all players.  Points from Mecatol Rex are the primary asymmetry in points, which is what lets a player hit the victory threshold a turn earlier than players that are matched with them on objectives.

The other advantage to holding it is that the planet has 6 influence (the most of any planet and tied for most of any system).  This allows a player to get two extra command tokens off of the Leadership strategy card (either primary or secondary ability) or can be used to help score any "Spend X influence" objectives (Sway the Council and Manipulate Galactic Law).  This also gives a player outsized voting power in the Agenda Phase.  Note that because planets refresh before the Agenda Phase, you get to both spend influence on command tokens or objectives and use Mecatol Rex to vote if you hold Mecatol Rex for the whole turn.

Note that some of these benefits can be obtained by controlling Mecatol Rex breifly, whereas others require holding it across turns.  Getting the caretakers token (worth 1 point) can be done with a pure smash and grab operation; getting it doesn't require you to hold Mecatol Rex for any duration (just to have taken it first).  Additionally, if you have picked the Imperial strategy card already this turn, you can take Mecatol Rex and score a point off of it in the same turn without having to hold it for very long.  Having the extra voting power requires you to be holding Mecatol Rex at the end of the turn.  Getting the extra command tokens or using Mecatol Rex's influence to score objectives are the benefits that are most tied to holding Mecatol Rex for a real duration, as planets you conquer are automatically exhausted and you usually need to wait for the status phase for them to unexhaust.